# Send from Drizzle useCacheSend hook sends trasactions twice

Tags: react, drizzle

I'm following the old documentation about [hooks](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/packages/react-plugin/README.md#usecachesend) and I'm getting a problem at sending transactions: every transaction is sent twice, why?

The next is the current core:

```
<form
            onSubmit={React.useCallback(
              ({
                to = drizzleState.clientAccount,
                value = toHex(parseAmountToToken(amountToSend, tokenDecimals)),
              }) => send(to, value),
              [amountToSend]
            )}
          >
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="value"
              onChange={(e) => setAmountToSend(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </form>
```

Also `TXObjects` is ever undefined:  `<div>{TXObjects?.map((t) => t.status)}</div>`.

I'm seeing the [`send` function](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/packages/react-plugin/src/hooks/create-use-cache-send.js#L16) is calling the contract method twice for each transaction:
[image: Screen Capture_select-area_20200903141705]

But I don't understand why it is happening.

Now, if i decide use `cacheSend` directly, i don't get duplicated transactions:

```
  const sendTokens = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    contract.cacheSend(
      drizzleState.clientAccount,
      toHex(parseAmountToToken(amountToSend, tokenDecimals))
    );
  };
```

Can anyone guide me? Is this a bug?

Comment: can you provide your implementation of useCacheSend() also?

Comment: This is the drizzle implementation: https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/packages/react-plugin/src/hooks/create-use-cache-send.js